# iptables still blocking server, even after removing

Tags: iptables

I'm having a bit of an issue with a Virtual Machine (VM) I have. Basically, I was trying to log into FTP on my web-server, but forgot the logins. As such, it has now blocked the VM's IP. I found it with:

```
iptables -L -n --line | grep "xxxxx"
```

Turns out it was blocked in the **ALLOWIN** and **ALLOWOUT** chains. So, I removed it with:

```
iptables -D ALLOWIN -s x.x.x.x -j DROP 
iptables -D ALLOWOUT -s x.x.x.x -j DROP
```

The saved the config:

```
 service iptables save
```

I even tried a reboot , using:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Then I try it on the VM, but it times out:

```
D:\Users\Andy>ping chambresdhotes.org

Pinging chambresdhotes.org [216.38.63.234] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 216.38.63.234:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what else I can try. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

FWIW, I have also done an:

```
iptable -L | grep 123.123.123.123
```

..but it gives no results (which I assume means there are no matching rules!)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm deciding if I should delete this question or not - but think it may be good to leave up, in case anyone else has a similar issue.

I found the problem. The VM is with Amazon, so I thought I'd just do a search for "amazon" in the `iptable -L`. Turned out there was an IP that was blocked:

```
LOGDROPOUT  all  --  anywhere             ec2-52-210-49-189.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I removed that one from both the **DENYIN** and **DENYOUT**, saved + restarted iptables, and voila... it works now!